# Handling ServerClick event of a dynamic HtmlInputSubmit control

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, submit

I am a beginner in ASP .Net programming.
I am developping a little training web application.
I have developped a web form where the user can add items into a cart.
The user's cart matches a session variable.

I check whether the user's cart is empty or not in the Page_PreRender event handler.
If the cart is not empty then a table is inserted into the form.
Each item in the cart matches a line in the table.
An item line contains an HtmlInputSubmit to remove the item from the cart.

Here is the code I have written to create dynamically the "Remove Item" HtmlInputSubmit :

```
submitSupprimerArt = new HtmlInputSubmit();
cellTblCaddie.Controls.Add(submitSupprimerArt);

submitSupprimerArt.Value = "Supprimer " + article.Id;
submitSupprimerArt.Attributes.Add("articleId", article.Id);
submitSupprimerArt.ServerClick += new EventHandler(submitSupprimerArt_Click);
```

When the user click the HtmlInputSubmit then a postback is made but the submitSupprimerArt_Click event handler is not called.
Can someone please give me a reason ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not want to but I have finally looked at the solution of the training application.
I can describe operations needed to solve my problem but I can not explain precisely why the operations must be done.

The trick is to declare a PlaceHolder control in the ASPX page.
The PlaceHolder must be filled with "Remove Item" buttons from the Page_Load event handler as follows :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // ...

    caddie = (ListeArticles)this.Session["caddie"];
    if (caddie != null)
    {
        foreach (Article article in caddie)
        {
            btnSupprimerArt = new Button();
            this.phBoutonsSupprArt.Controls.Add(btnSupprimerArt);

            btnSupprimerArt.ID = "btnSupprimerArt" + article.Id;
            btnSupprimerArt.Command += new CommandEventHandler(btnSupprimerArt_Command);
            btnSupprimerArt.CommandName = article.Id;
            btnSupprimerArt.Text = "Supprimer " + article.Id;
        }
    }
}
```

The Controls property of the PlaceHolder is cleared from the Page_PreRender event handler.
Then the "Remove Item" buttons are created from the Page_PreRender event handler.
The "Remove Item" buttons are inserted this time into table cells.

**Conclusion (Needs probably revision) :**
Registering handlers to dynamic control events seems a little tricky.
Apparently every event handlers must be registered after the Page_Load event.